# SchemaExport() vs. hbm2ddl.auto

Tags: hibernate

I'm new to hibernate. While writing hibernate code, I found that there are following two ways to generate the schema:

1. Using `new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true)` method
2. Using the XML configuration option hbm2ddl.auto

Can someone please explain what is difference between these two options and which one to use?
I'm using hibernate-distribution-3.3.2.G.A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one allows creating the schema when you want to, by executing this code.

The second one configures Hibernate to do it each time the session factory is created.